# svn export all but some directories

Tags: linux, bash, svn, export

I am doing a svn export of the repo to a temp location, then I remove some directories before I copy the code base to a deployment directory.

Is there a way to "exclude" a list of directories during the "export" command?

The reason for this is so that the export is faster (don't need to fetch stuff I remove in this deploy)tail  and therefore the deployment script is faster.

Comment: Belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the concept of `Sparse Directories Exclusion` to achieve this. For details on it, you can read it [here](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#sparse-directory-exclusion).

This [blog post](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/sparse-directories-now-with-exclusion) has also explained the above concept.

> Say I no longer care about what’s going on some directory of one my
>   project working copies. Maybe I don’t care about the Subversion
>   project’s website any more. Well, with this new exclusion feature, I
>   can tell Subversion to remove that directory:

```
$ cd ~/projects/subversion/trunk 
$ svn update --set-depth=exclude www
D         www 
$ ls www ls: cannot access www: No such file or directory 
$
```

> Done deal. When I update my working copy in the future, I
>   will not receive any changes aimed at that www directory. If I later
>   decide that I once again care about that directory, I can
>   “resubscribe” to it again:
>
> ```
> $ svn update --set-depth=infinity www 
> A    www 
> A    www/links.html 
> A    www/testing-goals.html 
> … 
> A    www/tigris-permissions.html 
> A    www/webdav-usage.html Updated to revision 36292. 
> $
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I was hoping for a "one command" but I guess three commands will do the trick in my case. Summary of steps: "svn update --set-depth=exclude; svn export; svn update set-depth=infinity;